# firefox developer tools compare to firebug / missing preview for ajax response

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

i know this question might get voted down and be closed but i have to put it out there

im windows user and i got familiar with firefox in the bad old days of IE reign 
i love firefox specially after i become a web developer and started to work with wonderful add-ons

but recent changes has made me to move to chrome more and more every day specifically i have to mention death of beloved firebug

i hate the firefox developer console , it feels awkward and clunky and primitive compare to firebug  and its not as user friendly as firebug

i have to ask , is it me or anyone else feels the same ?  cuz i've searched around and it doesn't seem to bother anyone else !

here is what bothers me the most .... modern web apps rely heavily on ajax calls , for some reason i cant find preview for ajax calls response in the firefox developer tools ... i can see server response as code but not rendered preview of server response

and i say i cant find it becuz i cant imagine possibility of not having preview .... just imagine your using a framework and it returns a stack error with lots of html/css style , its impossible to find the actual error among the heap of codes in developer tools response section

so aside from the rant  , basically  im hoping someone to say there is a preview  and this is how you can activated  it !

Comment: Please make your question more precise. This isn't a forum, so you should try to pinpoint your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the preview for responses got [removed in Firefox 55](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350229), obviously under the incorrect assumption that it duplicated some other UI.
Luckily it was added back for [Firefox 59](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353319), now placed [within the *Response* panel](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353319).

Here's a screenshot for how this looks like on this page:
[image: HTML response preview]

Comment: is there are a way we can make this as it was ? separate panes.

can't see the full preview at once without folding the response section or vise versa

Comment: There is no such option. You may [request an option](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Netmonitor), though, to persist the status of the code panel or minimize it by default.